# MySQL Connector/C++ with MariaDB

Tags: c++, mysql, debian, mariadb

I just learned that Debian 9 (releasing around June 2017) is replacing MySQL with MariaDB 10.  I have never used MariaDB before, but all of my C++ code works with MySQL using their [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/).

My question is, will this connector work with MariaDB?  Does the connector version matter at all?  Does anyone have any experience in connecting to MariaDB from C++?

I see Maria has a connector [here](https://launchpad.net/mariadb++), but where is their documentation on how to use it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/c-client-library/ the MariaDB projects recommends to use mariadbpp from https://github.com/viaduck/mariadbpp to access MariaDB databases from C++ code.

Comment: Thank you.  I am sticking with Ubuntu, which still uses MySQL.  I do not like MariaDB.

Comment: @xinthose I'm curious, why?

Comment: @cesargastonec I believe their product is not as mature as MySQL, the [most used database in the world](https://www.eversql.com/most-popular-databases-in-2018-according-to-stackoverflow-survey/).  The MySQL connector did not work for me on MariaDB two years ago, not sure about now though.

Comment: @xinthose Thank you. I'll keep it in mind. I'm starting (no choice) with C++ connectors for MariaDB on Linux Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/, you can try out the official MySQL connector here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/

There are step by step instructions on how to get it running.

Comment: Thank you.  Apparently all C++ and C# MySQL code still works on MariaDB (we just tested it).

Comment: I am getting this error with my code now `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES); MySQL Error Code = 1045; SQLState = 20000`.